# open particular salesforce lead id in browser from .net project using server url and sessionid

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am new to salesforce. I am doing the .net project. In which, I access the particular salesforce account by using username,password and token. I got all the lead details of that account in my .net project. I shown the result in datagridview. Now my need is? when i click the particulaar lead id in datagridview should open the browser with salesforce page of that particular lead details. I have serverurl,sessionid and lead id. How should i use these things to achieve my need.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get the salesforce page in browser from C#.net project.

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", @"https://ap1.salesforce.com/00Q9000000RsUkk");

Process.Start(startInfo);

the url:ap1.salesforce.com can get from sforce.loginresult when we login by using usrname,password and token. In the loginresult, we can get serverurl. From which we need  to get the url (ap1.salesforce.com). The Url will differ for every user.

the id:00Q9000000RsUkk is the id of salesforce lead or document etc,Which is need to open in browser from c#.net project